How best to store millions of pairs of 64 bit ints in a set?
I have millions of pairs of 64 bit integers I want to put into a set. Speed and space are important to me.
I could put tuples of python ints into the set but python ints use a lot more than 64 bits each. numpy has the type uint64 but I can’t add numpy arrays to a set afaik.
I would really like the RAM usage of storing one million pairs of ints to be as close to 128 million bits as possible.
I will be performing a lot of set add and query operations which I need to be fast.

How many millions of pairs? How many different 64 bit integers?

@nocomment I do it until it fills RAM.. The more I can store the better the result of my optimisation code will be.

But do you have many duplicate numbers or not?

@nocomment Yes there will be a lot of duplicates which why a set is so useful.

I mean in the set.

@nocomment Duplicates in a set…?

@deceze Yes. For example, {(x,y) for x in range(1000) for y in range(1000)} is a set of a million pairs, but almost all numbers are duplicates. Only a thousand different numbers.

When I find myself facing a problem like that, I wonder whether I am using the right tool. Here I would considere either a lightweight database (SQLite) if the processing time remains acceptable, or a lower level language (C, C++) if it does not.

Is there any chance you could give us a bigger picture of what you're trying to do? Are the tuples known in advance, but they're just added and queried in a random order?  What's going on that you have these strange constraints.

Think of a set as a dict, storing the keys in some sort of hash table (but no 'values').  Compared to numpy arrays, memory usage of sets and dicts is not nearly as predicable or controllable.

As a completely different solution, if you're willing to go 25% over budget, then you might be able to get away with a hash table, masquerading as a large numpy array:
SIZE = int(1_000_000 * 1.25)
table = np.zeros((SIZE, 2), dtype=np.int64)

Given an element that's not (0, 0), you'd insert or look up the element in the table using standard hash table open addressing algorithms. You have to treat (0,0) specially, by just having a variable is_00_in_table since it's the sentinel value for an empty table.
Using 25% more space gives you a maximum load factor of 80%, which is a reasonable value for a hash table.

You write a custom class around np.array, with custom hash function. E.g.
import numpy as np

class MySet:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.missing_value = np.iinfo(np.uint64).max
        self.data = np.full(size, self.missing_value, dtype=np.uint64)
        
    def __contains__(self, item):
        h = self.get_hash(item)
        # check if first value is not default, ideally should check all values
        return self.data[h][0] != self.missing_value
        
    def add(self, item):
        self.data[self.get_hash(item)] = item
        
    def get_hash(self, item):
        return hash(tuple(item)) % self.data.shape[0]
    
s = MySet( (10**6, 2) )
s.add( (5, 42) )

print( (5, 42) in s ) # True
print( (0, 0) in s ) # False
print( s.data.__sizeof__() ) # 16000128 bytes = 1 000 000 elements * 2 pair size * 8 bytes + numpy extra data


Why NumPy? You're not really using its functions, are you? If you only use it for compact storage, I think Python's array would be equally compact, and faster.

@nocomment I don't use it indeed, but I don't know if OP uses (needs to use) it. They mentioned NumPy, I just wrote a short example around it

I don’t need numpy, it just has  a 64 bit type .

This is going to have collision problems, since you don't have any way to detect or resolve collisions.

@user2357112 true, I was just trying to show a short example, obviously the complex hashing or dynamic memory management can be added on top

If you could tolerate a very small percent of false positives, and your only operations are add and is_member, then a Bloom Filter sounds perfect for you.
You would create a bitmap of size 128 million, and you'd also write say 8 hash functions that map a tuple into an integer between 0 and 128 million.   To add an element, you set the 8 bits that it maps to. To query an element, you test the 10 bits that it maps to and see if they are on.  (There is no easy way to delete an element.)
You could probably get away with size much less that 128 million.  You can tune the size of the bit map and the number of hashes to reduce the number of false positives.  (There are no false negatives).
The Wikipedia article gives a longer discussion on the appropriate number of hashes to use to minimize the number of False negatives, and what the probability of a false negative actually is, given the bitmap size (in bits) and the number of elements.

I don’t think that will work for me. I don’t know how many pairs I will insert in advance, I don’t want the overhead of calling 8 (for example) hash functions and I don’t really want false positives.

With 128_000_000 bits and 8 hash functions, your odds of a false positive are round about 2 in 10 billion.  This is how large hash sets are done in the real world.  Figured I'd at least let you know about their existence.

Thank you. I do like bloom filters in general.
